# Prove that for $\pi_g(\alpha)=\alpha g$, $\pi$ is a group action

Tags: matrices, group-theory, group-actions, principal-ideal-domains

Let $R$ a principal ideal domain and let $G$ the group of all the invertible members of $M_2(R)$. Let $\Omega :=R^2$. For all $g\in G$ let $\pi_g:\Omega\to\Omega$ defined by $\alpha \pi_g=\alpha g$ for all $\alpha=(x,y)\in\Omega$.
Prove that the map $\pi:G\to Sym(\Omega)$ defined by $g\mapsto \pi_g$ is an action of $G$ on $\Omega$.

In the solution I've managed to show that $\pi(I,\alpha)=\alpha$, (for $I=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
0 & 1
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$), but I cant prove $$\ \alpha g h\overset{def}{=}\pi(gh,\alpha)=\pi(g,\pi(h,\alpha))\overset{def}{=}\alpha hg \
$$

Comment: What makes you think that $\alpha gh = \alpha hg$? For a group action, you want to prove that $\alpha(gh) = (\alpha g)h$, along with what you’ve proven already.

Comment: @SantanaAfton I don't understand. Don't I need to show $\alpha gh= \alpha hg$? Because $\pi(gh,\alpha)=\alpha(gh)=\alpha gh$ and $\pi(g,\pi(h,\alpha))=\pi(g,\alpha h)=(\alpha h)g=\alpha hg$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your notation is giving you some roadblocks here.

> A (right) *group action* of a group $G$ on a set $\Omega$ is a map $G\times \Omega\to \Omega$ satisfying:
>
> - $x^e = x$ for any $x\in \Omega$
> - $(x^g)^h = x^{gh}$
>
> where the image of $(g,x)$ is denoted as $x^g$.

In this context, our action is defined as

$$\alpha^g := \pi(g,\alpha) := \alpha g.$$

I’m going to abandon the notation relying on $\pi$. If we want to prove that this is truly an action, then

$$(\alpha^g)^h = (\alpha g)^h = (\alpha g)h = \alpha (gh) = \alpha^{gh}.$$

Your mistake is that you stated that $\pi(gh,\alpha) = \pi(g, \pi(h,\alpha))$, or that $\alpha^{gh} = (\alpha^h)^g$, or that $\alpha(gh) = (\alpha h)g$. This doesn’t follow immediately from definitions — if it were true it would require some additional convincing.

Comment: You showed $(\alpha^g)^h=\alpha^{gh}$ i.e. $\pi(\textbf{h},\pi(\textbf{g},\alpha))=\pi(gh,\alpha)$ but we need to show $\pi(\textbf{g},\pi(\textbf{h},\alpha))=\pi(gh,alpha)$ @santana

Comment: @J.Doe Why do we need to show $(\alpha)^{gh} = (\alpha^h)^g$?